# Ajax.BeginForm in codebehind

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to use `Ajax.BeginForm` in the `Controller`? Cause I want to create a form in the `Controller` and then write it in the HTML after an AJAX request. Or is there a better way?

---

Now I use a `PartialView` but it doesn't work... How can I render it with Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm understanding your question as *you want to return an HTML fragment as a response to a client's AJAX request, but do not know how.*

---

Of course there is a better way. It's MVC and you really shouldn't have View code in your Controller unless you truly can't help it. :)

Just create a partial view and render it as a response by `return PartialView()`.

Comment: Worked great :) I am totally new to razor, so don't blame me for these easy questions :)